# Find all groups so that a surjective homomorphism exists

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I'm trying to solve the problem of finding all groups $G$ such that there exists a surjective homomorphism $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \to G$, if $n$ is greater than or equal to 2.

I'm really not sure where to start, is the First Isomorphism Theorem applicable in this case?

Comment: You are on the right track, given a surjective (note: not 'subjective') morphism $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \to G$, what information does the first isomorphism theorem (note: not 'theory') give you about $G$?

Comment: Does G have to be the image of the mapping?

Comment: Is $n$ fixed?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* [Since $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is cyclic, so is $G$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/480177/104041) Use Lagrange's theorem and the First Isomorphism Theorem to look at normal subgroups of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. Also, note that all subgroups of an abelian group are normal.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome, @lola.123.